# Таймер сообщений

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать таймер сообщений? То есть, пользователь вводит сообщение, и мне надо так, чтобы ответ присылался не моментально:

```
input("Нажми Enter")
# тут таймер, который задержит следующую строку на несколько секунд
print("Привет!")
input()
```

Версия: Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

```
import time
time.sleep(seconds)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep - python 2.x
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.sleep - python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Есть возможность использовать метод sleep. Необходимо его импортировать из библиотеки time, сделать это можно двумя способами: import time или from time import sleep. Лично я предпочитаю второй вариант, ибо sleep() проще читать, чем time.sleep(). На месте вашего комментария надо указать sleep(k), где k - кол-во секунд(именно секунд) на которое ваш код должен остановиться.